# How to add timestamp into my user session and set maximum inactivity duration?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I handled session using Play framework in my application like below code.

```
def login = Action {
    { implicit request =>

          val email = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("email")(0)
          val password = request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.get("password")(0)

          loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
              errors => BadRequest(html.login(errors,"Please enter valid username password")),
              //contact => Ok(html.login(loginForm,SignUpProcess.login(email,password)))
              contact => Redirect(routes.Application.home).withSession("email" -> email,"password" -> password)
          )
      }
  }

  def index = Action { request =>
    request.session.get("email").map{ user =>
        Redirect(routes.Application.home).withSession("email" -> user)
    }.getOrElse{
         Ok(views.html.login(loginForm,"Enter username password to login"))
    }

  }
```

I need to add timeout for my session. In Play documentation,

> There is no technical timeout for the session, which expires when the
>   user closes the web browser. If you need a functional timeout for a
>   specific application, just store a timestamp into the user Session and
>   use it however your application needs (e.g. for a maximum session
>   duration, maxmimum inactivity duration, etc.).

How to add timestamp into my user session and set maximum insctivity duration?

Comment: `.withSession("email" -> user+","+System.currentTimeMillis)` This does work right. But I guess if functionality keeps increasing you will have to start managing user state on server then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Configure timeout in  your Play application by setting values for configuration keys in conf/application.conf file.

```
application.session.maxAge
```

Session time-out, i.e. the maximum age of the session cookie. If not set, the session expires when you close your web browser. For example, **to set the session to one hour:**

```
application.session.maxAge=1h
```

**Remember the session for one week:**

```
application.session.maxAge=7d
```

Default: the session is based on a transient cookie expires when the browser is closed.

or
You can do something like :

During your login set a "last action time" to current time in the session.

In your Global class, override onRequest test if that flag exist

- if not, user has no session -> redirect to login silently
- if yes

  --- test if last time is more than 30min ago

  ```
       ------ if yes, session timeout -> add message to flash, rediect to login   
       ------ if no, update the flag with current time, let the page load
  ```

Comment: 1) If I set maxAge=1h,the session expires after 1 hour even my application is active(user working)? 2) Also my transient cookie not expires when the browser was closed?My session still remains.

Comment: to timeout for 10 min you should put `maxAge=1omin` when you put this i think default session will no work and your app session will en active for 10 min only

Comment: @Rahul Kulhari "if no, update the flag with current time, let the page load" How exactly would you do that from the onGlobalRequest handler? It only has access to the request object, it can't set any session variables.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it as follows. On every answer to the user I would write the current time to the session:

```
.withSession("currentTime" -> System.currentTimeMillis)
```

To ensure proper session time and email/password I would add an `Action` extension like this:

```
def withEmail(f: String => EssentialAction): EssentialAction =
            Security.Authenticated(
                            currentEmailOpt,
                            r => Redirect(views.html.login(loginForm,"Enter username password to login")) )(f)

private
def currentEmailOpt(request: RequestHeader): Option[String] = 
    for{
      currentTime <- request.session.get("currentTime")
      deltaMs = System.currentTimeMillis - currentTime.toLong
      if deltaMs < 10*60*1000
      email <- request.session.get("email")
    }
      yield email
```

The `Action` extension is used as follows:

```
def index = withEmail(email => 
   Action { request =>
     Ok(views.html.index(email)).withSession("email" -> email, "currentTime" -> System.currentTimeMillis)
   }
)
```

(you may have a look at https://github.com/Primetalk/todo-list/blob/master/app/controllers/SecuredController.scala and it's usage at https://github.com/Primetalk/todo-list/blob/master/app/controllers/Task.scala).

**UPD:**(regards to @kliron) The above `withSession` will replace the whole session. If you need to store there some other info, then you need to save it:

```
.withSession(session + "currentTime" -> System.currentTimeMillis)
```

and

```
def index = withEmail(email => 
   Action { request =>
     Ok(views.html.index(email)).withSession(session + "currentTime" -> System.currentTimeMillis)
   }
)
```

Comment: Don't you mean .withSession(session + ("currentTime" -> ...))? Otherwise .withSession will overwrite any existing keyvals.

Comment: See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash
It seems that the session is updated by `withSession`. To discard the whole session one needs `withNewSession`.

Comment: I quote from your link: "Note that this will replace the whole session. If you need to add an element to an existing Session, just add an element to the incoming session, and specify that as new session". More plainly, use: .withSession(session + ("key" -> val)) if you want to preserve the previous key-value pairs in the session or .withSession("key"->val) if you want the session to only contain this key-pair.

Comment: Stap my vitals! Seems you are right. I'll fix the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like @arseniy-zhizhelev suggested

I had this same problem and added a timestamp (tick) to the session and updated it with each request after checking for a timeout.

Something like this:

```
// see if the session is expired
String previousTick = session("userTime");
if (previousTick != null && !previousTick.equals("")) {
  long previousT = Long.valueOf(previousTick);
  long currentT = new Date().getTime();
  long timeout = Long.valueOf(Play.application().configuration().getString("sessionTimeout")) * 1000 * 60;
  if ((currentT - previousT) > timeout) {
    // session expired
    session().clear();
    return null;
  } 
}
// update time in session
String tickString = Long.toString(new Date().getTime());
session("userTime", tickString);
```

http://www.poornerd.com/2014/04/01/how-to-implement-a-session-timeout-in-play-framework-2/

Then add a sessionTimeout=15 (in Minutes) to your conf file.