# How to clear session after some idle time in play framework

Tags: java, session, playframework, playframework-2.0

In Play framework 2.0, how to clear session values (or invalidate session) after some certain idle time is encountered?

I've gone through Internet but found no relevant answers for my query. I've found some solution for Version 1.x in [this link](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.5/configuration), even the documentation says that  `application.session.maxAge` concept in v1.x sets the session's max age, not the idle time duration. Unfortunately, I couldn't find such configurations for v2.x so far.

Is there a way to do so? Can someone help pls.

Comment: i hope u can store a timestamp in users session like maximum session duration ,idle time or inactivity time and after that u can clear session values..

Comment: any code samples pls.

Comment: check out:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19809764/how-to-add-timestamp-into-my-user-session-and-set-maximum-inactivity-duration